# How to export vApp and Resource Pool configuration?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, hypervisor, vcenter

I am creating a new site with VMware ESXi 6.0 u2 and vCenter 6.0 u2.

Is there any way I can export my vApp and my Resource pool configuration from my old site running ESXi 5.5 to this new one?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using PowerShell? Can something like the scripts in https://communities.vmware.com/thread/470348 work?

Answer (score 1):

Vmware has this ability to export/import vm's/vApps as either a .ovf or .ova files. The .ova is one file containing all your vm/vApp details (think of it as a .zip file) while .ovf is more of a folder containing all the different "bits" inside a vm (ie vmdk's, vmx's etc etc).

Note: I would recommend exporting as an .ova as they are easier to deal with.

**Exporting the vApp:**

You can Export the vApp as detailed here:
https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc%2FGUID-B05A4E9F-DD21-4397-95A1-00125AFDA9C8.html

**Importing the vApp:**

Save the .ova to a local disk then import it into your vSphere 6 environment as detailed here:
https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-17BEDA21-43F6-41F4-8FB2-E01D275FE9B4.html

**Resource Pool:**

As for the Resource Pool, you will have to do it programatically:
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/470348?start=0&tstart=0

The above link is a good start, but it really depends on your application, Good Luck
:-)